# Programmatically post form or execute JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup

Using Jsoup, I'm getting the following page:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>No Login </title>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.forms['login'].submit()">
        <div>
            <center>
                <form name="login" method="post" action="">
                    <input hidden="hidden" type="submit" value=""/>
                </form>
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to automatically call what's defined within the onload event, or automatically submit the hidden form. Is jsoup the right API to achieve it? As far as I understood JavaScript can't be executed by jsoup.

Comment: Very unclear what you are actually asking about. Do you want to generate this type of form using java as a string output ? Please make your requirement clear

Comment: No, I want to programmatically submit the form above. I have a first URL which returns me the above, now I need to submit the form from java without any user interaction.

Comment: Does this work?

Comment: If you want to submit a form, which is completely in the front-end, why not just stick to javascript? It seems like a major hassle to do with anything else.

Comment: just a minute: first you are calling a service which is returning you the above form as a string right ?

Comment: jsoup is not made to run JavaScript..... Sounds to me you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I think I can understand your requirement. If you are calling a webservice which is giving the response ,at client side, as above, simply append the html somewhere om your existing html and then call submit method from javascript. You may add some special attribute to identify the form like id/class and assign some values to it/these and call the element by this attribute values

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is what you want. Jsoup is an HTML parser, while Selenium is a automatic browser. There are some similar things in other languages, such as phantomjs, chrome headless.